# SQL JOIN values to ARRAY to create another ARRAY field

Tags: sql, arrays, json, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

maybe my searching is poor, but I couldn't find this question or answer anywhere.

Suppose I have a table CLASSROOM like:

```
[ { teacher_id: T1,
    students: [S11, S12, S13]},
  { teacher_id: T2,
     students: [S21, S22, S23]}]
```

The "students" field is an array of student_id's.  There is also a table STUDENTS like:

```
[ { id: S11, name: "Aaron"}, { id: S12, name: "Bob"}, { id: S13, name: "Charlie"},
  { id: S21, name: "Amy"}, { id: S22, name: "Becky"}, { id: S23, name: "Cat"} ]
```

I want to create the output table which has rows like:

```
[ { teacher_id: T1,
    students: [S11, S12, S13 ],
    names: [ "Aaron", "Bob", "Charlie" ] },
  { teacher_id: T2,
    students: [S21, S22, S23 ],
    names: [ "Amy", "Becky", "Cat" ] } ]
```

(Yes, this example is silly, but I don't want to bore you with my case.)

I suppose I could FLATTEN the CLASSROOM table, then do a straight join, but my real table is large & complicated enough that I want to avoid it if I can.  Is there a better way?

Note: assume students can be in multiple classes.  Teachers (`teacher_id`) are unique.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: postgresql, mysql, oracle...?

Comment: I do not understand your use of array notation here. Taken literally, it would seem that your CLASSROOM table always has a single row with a single array value in it (presumably with a data type of either ARRAY or VARIANT), since your example is "[ { teacher_id: T1,
    students: [S11, S12, S13]},
  { teacher_id: T2,
     students: [S21, S22, S23]}]". The same thing for your STUDENTS table. Is this what you are intending to convey? Or do you mean to say that you have 2 rows in your CLASSROOM table, each with a single dictionary value?

Comment: Thank you for reading.  The CLASSROOM table has two fields: "teacher_id" and "students" (an array); it has 2 rows.  The STUDENTS table 2 fields: "id" and "name"; it has 6 rows.
The desired output table will have 2 rows (like CLASSROOM) but with a 3rd column called "names" which is also an array.

Comment: For sake of clarity, here's the Snowflake syntax for building the example tables:
`create table CLASSROOM (teacher_id  VARCHAR, students  ARRAY);
insert into CLASSROOM select $1, parse_json($2) 
from values ('T1','["S11","S12","S13"]'),('T2','["S21","S22","S23"]');
create table STUDENTS (id VARCHAR, name VARCHAR);
insert into STUDENTS values ('S11','Aaron'),('S12','Bob'),('S13','Charlie'),('S21','Amy'),('S22','Becky'),('S23','Cat');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff, I got the following to work in Snowflake:

```
create table CLASSROOM (teacher_id  VARCHAR, students  ARRAY);
insert into CLASSROOM select $1, parse_json($2) 
from values ('T1','["S11","S12","S13"]'),('T2','["S21","S22","S23"]');

create table STUDENTS (id VARCHAR, name VARCHAR);
insert into STUDENTS values ('S11','Aaron'),('S12','Bob'),('S13','Charlie'),('S21','Amy'),('S22','Becky'),('S23','Cat');

select teacher_id, 
    array_agg(s.value::String) as student_ids, 
    array_agg(ss.name) as student_names
from CLASSROOM, table(flatten(input => CLASSROOM.students, mode => 'array')) s 
join STUDENTS ss on ss.id = s.value
group by teacher_id, s.SEQ
order by teacher_id;
```

Comment: Could you also please paste DDL and insert statement to prepare table and Data.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to flatten the array and reaggregate.  I'm not 100% sure of the syntax in Snowflake, but I think this will work:

```
select c.*,
       (select array_agg(ss.name) within group (order by s.index) as student_names
        from table(flatten(input => c.students, mode => 'array')) s join
             students ss
             on ss.id = s.value
       ) as names
from classroom c;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Gave me great food for thought, but with Snowflake, I'm getting "SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated".  Any further advice?